# What is recommended best practice for separating environments and micro-service contexts within AWS CloudWatch log groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I'd like to ask how to best organize AWS CloudWatch **log groups** for different environments such as

- dev
- staging
- prod

for a microservice architecture such that there exists say 50 microservices, each containing its own context (ex. payment, catalog, shipping, etc)

Variants I can think of for organizing unique and distint log groups are:

1. Log Group per Environment per Microservice (**150** total when number of
   environments is 3 and applications is 50)
2. Log Group per environment for all microservices (**3** total when number
   of environments is 3)

Are there any other recommended ways of organizing Log Groups? What types of attributes of the overall system should I take into consideration when deciding between these 2 or any others?

The trade off of me doing #1 is that I will have quiet a bit of log groups to maintain, although already prefiltered per app context.

Benefit of me doing #2 is less log groups to maintain overall, and perhaps single experience of obtaining logs per environment?